# How to count the number of properties in a class?

Tags: .net, vb.net

We're working with a webservice that demands 5 strings being posted to it in order to print an address label.  On our server, the data is held in an array so that it can be processed prior to being sent to the webservice.

We have a method that converts a multi0line `TextBox` string (the postal address) into the correct format, like this:

```
Public Class PostageLabel
    Public Property Address1 As String
    Public Property Address2 As String
    Public Property Address3 As String
    Public Property Address4 As String
    Public Property Address5 As String
End Class

Public Shared Function ConvertAddress(address As String) As PostageLabel
    Dim labelFieldsAvailable As Integer = 5 
    ' ...
End Function
```

The `labelFieldsAvailable` variable is simply the number of `Address` fields on a label (i.e. the number of `Public String` Properties present in the `PostageLabel` class).

As you can see, we're setting this manually in the function which isn't a big deal, but I was wondering if this value can be discovered automatically and avoid a potential bug (e.g. if the label format ever changes into 6 fields)?

```
Dim labelFieldsAvailable As Integer = (Some wizardry to count property fields)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use reflection to get the `PropertyInfo`s using [`GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx). Then simply return the `Length` of the array:

```
Dim l As Integer = GetType(PostageLabel).GetProperties().Length
```

Or, as [James Thorpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/791010/james-thorpe) suggested: to be totally safe, you can check if the name of the property starts with `Address` using a lamdba expression:

```
Dim l as Integer = GetType(PostageLabel).GetProperties().Count(Function(p) p.Name.StartsWith("Address"))
```

Comment: Just writing this myself!  However, as an additional check for future proofness, you can look for just `Address` properties: `Dim l as Integer = GetType(PostageLabel).GetProperties().Count(Function(p) p.Name.StartsWith("Address"))`

Comment: Wow.  Two fantastic answers and a real learning experience.  Thank you both very much.